# Getting model name of an object in django template

Tags: javascript, django

I need to get the model name of an object in a javascript function inside the template file. I have tried two methods. 1) Writing a custom templatetag

```
@register.filter  
def get_model_name(value):
    name = str(value.__class__.__name__)
    return name
```

Second is writing a method in the model itself

```
def getModelName(self):
    return 'Model1'
```

JS

```
var objectType = {{object.getModelName}};

var objectType = {{object | get_model_name}};
```

I get the correct name as output but its not in string format. So I get an  error saying that Model1 is undefined. Its being treated like a variable.

Any way to get this in string format. I need the name of the model in  string format in my var objectType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* a python string...you're just not passing it to JS as a string. You need to quote the value that is returned:

```
var objectType = '{{ object|get_model_name }}';
```

Comment: Yes, will do as soon as I'm allowed to.